# Jousting Mage needs more CMB

Tags: pathfinder-1e

For reasons best not asked++ about my Wizard is a day or two from entering a jousting tournament where the joust is a series of attacks using CMB/CMD as bullrushes. Being Strength 10 and a Wizard he's not exactly going to shine here but he's got a few tricks up his sleeve to improve matters

- Polymorph into another medium race to get a racial bonus to strength
- Cast [Transformation](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/transformation.html) to increase BAB (and thus CMB) as well as getting enhancement bonuses to Strength and Dex
- Possibly use enlarge as well (he will be riding a T-Rex) but I'm unsure if this is worth it

What other ways can he use to increase his CMB/CMD or survivability and turn him into a jousting hero?

- No items unless they're cheap and easily obtainable
- Wizard only spells
- No feats

++ Why has noone else in the party got the ride skill?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often overlooked when computing of a creature's [Combat Maneuver Bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Bonus) is this: "Add [to your attack roll to make the combat maneuver] any bonuses you currently have on attack rolls due to spells, feats, and other effects." Likewise, "A creature can also add any circumstance, deflection, dodge, insight, luck, morale, profane, and sacred bonuses to AC to its" [Combat Maneuver Defense](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Combat-Maneuver-Defense).

Combined, this means it's less a matter of some specifically perfect spell turning a creature into a jousting machine (like the paladin spell [*saddle surge*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/saddle-surge/)) and more of a matter of accumulating increasingly obscure bonuses from Dumpster-diving for increasingly wacky low-level, long-lasting spells that can be employed (probably either cast from scrolls or chugged as potions) right before the event.

If the wizard can already cast [*transformation*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/transformation/) and is riding a [tyrannosaurus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/dinosaur/tyrannosaurus/), he's to the point where a lot of this Dumpster-diving's probably already been done, either by him or by the rest of the party. If you can't get [*greater herosim*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/heroism/) there's [*contagious zeal*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/contagious-zeal/). If you can't hire a bunch of folks to beat on you with itty-bitty weapons to pump up your [*resilient reservoir*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/resilient-reservoir/), there's [*tactical acumen*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/tactical-acumen/). And so on. Even that old standby [*true strike*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-strike/) is handy in pinch for at least one pass on the lists.

Thus a comprehensive catalog all your options here is impossible. Instead, see what the town has available by way of potions and scrolls, buy 'em, and use 'em, and hope that the other guy didn't do the same thing.

Comment: true strike spell could help.

Comment: Quickened True Strikes saved the day! :)